# How to hide APIs when swagger is not authorized and show APIs when swagger is authorized

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

[Authorize Swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuCcY.png)

Is there a way to show APIs when the swagger is authorized in runtime?
I use `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` to hide APIs. I expect this: if unauthorized (firstload), then `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]`, if authorized, then `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = false)]`